# Segmentation fault in C while using getchar()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am writing a program that can read letters and it gives to them values `2^n`, so `a=2^0`, `b=2^1`....`z=2^25` and then I sum them. Somewhere in the input must be `|` and I count letters before and letter after it separately - `sum[0]=` before `|`, `sum[1]=` after `|`. When I type `aeoifha|shzs`, everything is OK, but when I type `|abc` or `abc|`, it gives me Segmentation fault, but I need it to tell me it is `sum[0]=0` and `sum[1]=7` for `|abc` or `sum[0]=7` and `sum[1]=0` for `abc|`. If there is just `|`, it is Wrong. The output is really Wrong, but it also gives me Segmentation fault.

Here is the code:

```
const int table[] = {1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,16384,32768,65536,131072,262144,524288,1048576,2097152,4194304,8388608,16777216,33554432};
const char *a_z = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
long long int sum[2] = {0};
int ch, count = 0;

for(;;)
{
    if(!islower(ch = getchar()))
    {
        if(ch == '\n' && sum[0] && sum[1])
            break;
        else if(ch == EOF)
            {
            printf("Wrong.\n");
            }
        else if(ch == '|' && sum[0] != 0 && count == 0)
            {
            count = 1;
            continue;
            }
    printf("Wrong.\n");
    sum[0] = sum[1] = count = 0;
    while(ch != '\n' && (ch=getchar())!=EOF && ch != '\n')
    continue;
    }
sum[count] += table[strchr(a_z, ch) - a_z];
}
```

Any idea how to get rid of the fault and how to give sum[]=0?

Comment: The way to get rid of the fault is to find the cause first. The way to find the cause is to use a debugger.

Comment: If you want help please format your code with correct indentation and tell us the *exact* test input.

Comment: I suspect this line isn't doing what you expect:  

    sum[count] += table[strchr(a_z, ch) - a_z];

Comment: `while(ch != '\n' && (ch=getchar())!=EOF && ch != '\n')
    continue;` --> `while(ch != '\n' && (ch=getchar())!=EOF && ch != '\n')
    ; continue;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before updating the `sum[count]`, you don't have checked if the `strchr(a_z, ch)` is not NULL, meaning that `ch` is not an expected `'a'...'z'` character.

After entering `"abc|"` and pressing 'Return' key, an additional `'\n' = 0x0A` is parsed but not filtered by `if(ch == '\n' && sum[0] && sum[1]) break;` because `sum[1]` is equal to `0`.

**First modification:** (Stop even when left or right is missing)

> But, to prevent a missing `'|'`, the break-condition shall be true
>   only when `count = 1` (equal `'|'` detection).

```
    if(!islower(ch = getchar()))
    {
        if(ch == '\n' && (sum[0] || sum[1]) && (count == 1))
```

Instead of

```
    if(!islower(ch = getchar()))
    {
        if(ch == '\n' && sum[0] && sum[1])
```

**Second modification** (force to switch to count=1 even left is missing):

```
        else if(ch == '|' && count == 0)
        {
            count = 1;
```

Instead of

```
        else if(ch == '|' && sum[0] != 0 && count == 0)
        {
            count = 1;
```

And to prevent unexpected `ch` value, filter before:

```
    if (strchr(a_z, ch)!=NULL) { // only 'a' to 'z' characters
        sum[count] += table[strchr(a_z, ch) - a_z];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! But now when I enter letters without |, it doest say "Wrong", but it counts the letters. So how can I add a condition, that even if sum[0]=0, there still has to be '|' int the beginning (the same for the end - for example ssdfkljsdfois|)?

Comment: Add `&& (count == 1)` in the break-condition to be sure that `'|'` has been detected.